# Java Bank Account Logic

Tags: java, logic, boolean-logic

I am trying to create a bank account class with few tools such as Balance, Deposit and withdrawal. I created super class and two sub class. One of the sub class(checking account) needs to charge a 10$ fee after 2 transactions.

I am having small trouble in the following program. It is a minor part of the program and I tried everything but I can not think of the solution. The problem is marked with star box comment in the code. The bank account (super Class) class is attached for your reference.

It is charging the transaction fee even though withdrawal is failed due to unavailability of enough balance. I understand why it is doing that but can someone suggest any solution?

```
//This is the sub Class "Checking Account" 
public class CheckingAccount  extends BankAccount
{
//Private Instance Variablea
private double dTransFee;
private int iFreeCheckPerMonth;
private int iNumChecks;
//Constructor
public CheckingAccount(String sName, int iAccountNumber)
{
    super(sName, iAccountNumber);
     dTransFee = 10;
     iFreeCheckPerMonth = 2;
     iNumChecks=0;
}
//Overriding method from the Bank Account Class
public boolean bWithdrawl (double dMoney)
{
    if (iNumChecks<2)
    {
        super.bWithdrawl(dMoney);
        iNumChecks++;
        iFreeCheckPerMonth--;
    }
    else 
    {
        /****************************
         * I DON'T KNOW HOW I CAN MAKE STATEMENT SUCH AS
         * IF BWITHDRAL IS FALSE(FAILS) DON'T TAKE OUT 10 FROM BALANCE.
         ***************************/
        super.bWithdrawl(dMoney);
        dBalance = dBalance- dTransFee;
        iNumChecks++;
        iFreeCheckPerMonth--;
    }
    return false;
}

//Prints how many checks are left
    public int FreeChecksLeft ()
{       
    return iFreeCheckPerMonth; 
}

//Prints how many checks have been used
public int CheckUsed ()
{
    return iNumChecks;
}
```

}

```
//Super Class

/**************************************************************
*Name: BankAccount
*Input:Name and account number. Deposit and withdrawal amount for methods
*Output: None
*Description:
* Date: 10/19/2017 Author: Apurva Gandhi
**************************************************************/
public class BankAccount 
{
//Private Instance Variable
protected double dBalance;
protected int iAccountNum;
protected String sOwnerName;

//Constructor
public BankAccount (String sName, int iAccountNumber)
{
    iAccountNum = iAccountNumber;
    sOwnerName = sName;
}
/**************************************************************
*Name: deposit
*Input:amount of money
*Output: none
*Description: takes the amount of money and add the amount to the balance. 
* Date: 10/19/2017 Author: Apurva Gandhi
**************************************************************/
//Method for deposit
public void deposit(double dMoney)
{
    dBalance += dMoney;

}
/**************************************************************
*Name: Withdrawal
*Input:amount of money
*Output: none
*Description: takes the amount of money and subtracts the amount from the balance. 
* Date: 10/19/2017 Author: Apurva Gandhi
**************************************************************/
//Method for Withdrawal
public boolean bWithdrawl (double dMoney)
{
    if (dMoney <= dBalance)
    {
    dBalance -= dMoney;
    }
    return false;
}
//Method to get balance
public double getBalance()
{
    return dBalance;
}
```

}

```
//Here is the tester for Checking Account
```

public class CheckingTester
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Create Checking account
    CheckingAccount ca1 = new CheckingAccount ("Apurva", 1000);

    //Make deposit
    ca1.deposit(500);

    //Verify that it worked
    System.out.println("After deposit the balance is: " + ca1.getBalance()+" Expected:500");

    //Check #1
    //Test a withdrawal
    ca1.bWithdrawl(100);

    //Verify that it worked
    System.out.println("After withdrawal the balance is : " + ca1.getBalance()+ " Expected 400");

    //Checks the number of free checks available for use
    ca1.FreeChecksLeft();
    System.out.println("Number of Free Checks left are: "+ca1.FreeChecksLeft()+ " Expected 1");

    //Check how many checks have been used 
    ca1.CheckUsed();
    System.out.println("The number of check used are: "+ ca1.CheckUsed()+(" Expected 1"));

    //Check #2
    ca1.bWithdrawl(100);
    System.out.println("After withdrawal the balance is : " + ca1.getBalance()+ " Expected 300");

    //Check 3
    ca1.bWithdrawl(100);
    System.out.println("After withdrawal the balance is : " + ca1.getBalance()+ " Expected 190");

    //Check 4
    ca1.bWithdrawl(200);
    System.out.println("After withdrawal the balance is : " + ca1.getBalance()+ " Expected 190");

    }
```

}

Comment: Why does `bWithdrawal()` always return false?

Comment: `if (!super.bWithdrawl(dMoney)) { // do stuff }` ???

Comment: @MadProgrammer That did not work well. I tried                                                    
    if 
    (!super.bWithdrawl(dMoney))
     {
    return false;
     }
   else
   {
   super.bWithdrawl(dMoney);
   dBalance = dBalance- dTransFee;
   iNumChecks++;
   iFreeCheckPerMonth--;
   }

Comment: I think shmosel has highlighted a key issue

Comment: @shmosel I am guessing it only returns false if the balance is more than the withdrawal amount. However, it is not bothering me right now. I do not know if that can effect the transaction fee.

Comment: Sir @MadProgrammer So how do I solve that issue? Do I change that to true?

Comment: You should return a value that represents the success of the operation

Comment: @MadProgrammer Because I am very new to Programming, I am having hard time in figuring out the value. Can you provide an example of what do you mean by value?

Comment: Never *guess* what your code does.